# prolog : how to find all the solutions of a predicate in a list

Tags: list, count, prolog, predicate

I have a list L =[a,b,c,d,e] and I would like to know  all the variables in this list that check a predicate P.

I do not know how to do it. Please do you have some pist ?

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding what you're asking for but I wonder if the predicate you want is `include/3`?

See: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=include/3

Example query:

```
include(between(3,6), [6,3,2,8,5], Result).
```

Outcome:

```
Result = [6, 3, 5]
```

`Result` contains all elements of the second argument (i.e. `[6,3,2,8,5]`) for which the goal represented by the first argument (i.e. `between(3,6)`) succeeds.